# Anyone face any issues with jquery.on('change') or .change() on ios 12.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

For some reason after the recent update to ios 12.2 my jquery on or change functions aren't working. There are no javascript errors and when I check the elements I can see they have a change event bound to them.

This only happens with ios 12.2 on phones no matter what browser I try. The same issue happens MacOS with safari 12.1.

If anyone has faced this problem or have an idea as to how to debug it I would appreciate it

Comment: I see the same over here. on( 'input' ) has completely stopped working in Safari 12.1 macOS. Will investigate...

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? It turned out that for some reason I was running jQuery 1.4.2, which is really old. Upgraded jQuery to 3.3.1 and all is well. Seems to be an incompatibility with older jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have seen similar behaviour on drop-down lists since 12.2 released.

What we see is that the page refreshes after interacting with drop-down list ( which has a event on it) and the user loses the choice they selected.

We are currently debugging our own code, and naturally came here to see if any one else is facing the same problem. We are on JQuery 2.2.4 currently.

Last year, I faced a problem where an old JQuery 1.9 style call broke only on iPAd. Worked fine on Chrome iPad emulator. Upgrading to 2.2.4 fixed the problem. ;
Again, we are seeing this new behaviour can not be seen on emulators, only on a real device.